# sql table and values "merging" or hand-in-hand

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with tne name users, and one with users2 users I have one value with the name "hand", and on users2 I have one value with the name "win".

Is it possible that the "win" is equal to "hand" or wise versa? If one of them updates, the 
another one updates too with the new value.

Comment: Do you use MSSQL or do you use MySQL? This is quite an importent difference.

Comment: Dear Bernhard, im using MySQL :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can't do this automatically on a MySQL database. You could do this with two seperate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place an update trigger on one table to fire when a row is updated, which updates the other table, the syntax for creating triggers can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: could you give me an example of it?:)